# pencil prototyping won't launch

Tags: 18.04, pencil

I downloaded Pencil from https://pencil.evolus.vn and installed the .deb file successfully but whenever I try to open the application nothing happens. it appears in the dock for a few moments but it won't open. is there something missing?!

I'm on ubuntu 18.4 (kernel version : 4.17)

Comment: what happens if you start pencil from the command line? (Open Terminal and type "pencil")

Comment: it returns "pencil: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"  seems I have to add libgconf library but how do I do that?

Comment: I installed missing library using "sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4" and it worked :) thanks for your comment @SebastianStark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running the program in question from the terminal. This often gives a better view of what might be going wrong when it is not starting. Especially if you installed a program via `dpkg`, which has no dependency tracking built in like `apt`, you can easily forget some package the application needs to work.

Watch out for missing library packages in particular.

In this case the package depends on the libgconf-2-4 package, which you can install using the following command:

```
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
```